# How to make 2 vstacks align properly?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, layout, alignment

i've been trying to make a good design for an app, however i've run into a problem. The design consists of 2 vstacks in 1 hstack and the problem occurs when a text view in a vstack wraps. this makes the text views that are under the vstack be unaligned. is there any way to make them always aligned? here is the relevant code.

this is file of a single vertical row, where the problem is located at, i presume

```
import SwiftUI

struct VerticalRowView: View {
    var whichOfTheFour: Int
    var movie: Movie
    @Binding var detailScreenShown: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 25) {
                if whichOfTheFour == 1 {
                    Text("Title:")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            detailScreenShown = true
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.cyan)
                    Text("Genre:")
                    Text("Released:")
                    Text("Origin:")
                    Text("Rated:")
                    Text("Runtime:")
                    Text("Plot:")
                }
                else if whichOfTheFour == 2 {
                    Text("Director:")
                    Text("Actor:")
                    Text("Writer:")
                    Text("Languages:")
                    Text("Box office:")
                }
                else if whichOfTheFour == 3 {
                    Text("Awards:")
                    Text("Metascore:")
                    Text("IMDB Rating:")
                    Text("IMDB Votes:")
                }
                else if whichOfTheFour == 4 {
                    Text("DVD:")
                    Text("Production:")
                }
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 25) {
                if whichOfTheFour == 1 {
                    Text(movie.title ?? "Unknown")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            detailScreenShown = true
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.cyan)
                    Text(movie.genre ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.released ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.country ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.rated ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.runtime ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.plot ?? "Unknown")
                }
                else if whichOfTheFour == 2 {
                    Text(movie.director ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.actor ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.writer ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.language ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.boxOffice ?? "Unknown")
                }
                else if whichOfTheFour == 3 {
                    Text(movie.awards ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.metascore ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.imdbRating ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.imdbVotes ?? "Unknown")
                }
                else if whichOfTheFour == 4 {
                    Text(movie.DVD ?? "Unknown")
                    Text(movie.production ?? "Unknown")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the implementation

```
struct MovieDetailView: View {
    @Binding var result: Movie
    @Binding var detailScreenShown: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            CustomDivider()
            
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: result.poster ?? ""))
            
            CustomDivider()
            
            VerticalRowView(whichOfTheFour: 1, movie: result, detailScreenShown: $detailScreenShown)

            CustomDivider()
            
            VerticalRowView(whichOfTheFour: 2, movie: result, detailScreenShown: $detailScreenShown)
            
            CustomDivider()
            
            VerticalRowView(whichOfTheFour: 3, movie: result, detailScreenShown: $detailScreenShown)
            
            CustomDivider()
            
            VerticalRowView(whichOfTheFour: 4, movie: result, detailScreenShown: $detailScreenShown)
        }
    }
}
```

ive been trying to solve this for over 6 hours, im still a newbie and i believe the solution is very silly.

Comment: You should be using [`Table`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/table)

Comment: is there any way of using just stacks? or table is just superiour?

Comment: Table is far superior for your use case, but I demonstrated below one way of how you can only use stacks... Although I think having 2 VStacks makes it very hard (you'd need to somehow limit height of the rows...), so I did something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, I recommend using Table - it fits your use case like a glove, but if you have to replicate the same behavior without a Table, then I would do this:

- First of all, instead of having 2 `VStack`s, have one
- And inside it, express each row as `HStack`, using the `GeometryReader` to ensure that all left and right columns align.

Something like this:

First, the row view, with title and optional value, which we will resolve to `Unknown` if it has no value:

```
struct MovieRowView: View {
    
    let title: String
    let value: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { metrics in
            HStack {
                Text("\(title):")
                    .frame(
                        width: metrics.size.width * 0.4,
                        alignment: .topTrailing
                    )
                Text(value ?? "Unknown")
                    .frame(
                        width: metrics.size.width * 0.6,
                        alignment: .topLeading
                    )
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

As you see, the `GeometryReader` is used to ensure that every row will have exactly the same split between left and right column. In addition, we can align left column to the `trailing` edge, and right column to `leading` edge, so they are closer to each other. You can change any of the proportions / alignment based on your needs of course.

Next, lets put all the rows into `VStack`:

```
struct MovieView: View {
    
    // ...
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MovieRowView(title: "Title", value: movie.title)
                .onTapGesture {
                    detailScreenShown = true
                }
                .foregroundColor(.cyan)
            MovieRowView(title: "Genre", value: movie.genre)
            MovieRowView(title: "Released", value: movie.released)
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm using a slightly modified version of this code snippet. works perfectly!